# Problem to install Eclipse on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I installed Ubuntu 15.04 on the VM and I have downloaded **Eclipse Luna**.
When I try to install it, this error occurs:

> An error has occurred.
>   See the log file
>   `/home/master/.eclipse/1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/1442224462970.log`

Can you help me to fix  it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.com! As it stands your question is completely unclear. Please edit the text. Also, if the error you get is described in a log file, please include the contents of that log file.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include not only *how* you tried to install Eclipse (downloaded from where, which commands did you run, ...), but also the content of the mentioned error log file. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

*Update*

Instead using the next steps, you could also use the new [Eclipse Installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), and have a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/695401/367165) answer.

---

1. Check your Java installation with

   ```
   java -version
   ```

   you should see something like this

   ```
   java version "1.8.0_60"
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
   Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
   ```

   If necessary install Java

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```
2. Remove your Eclipse installation
3. Download a newer version of eclipse [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), eg. [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 64-bit](https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).
4. Extract the archive

   Replace the filename id necessary

   ```
   sudo tar xf eclipse-jee-mars-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C /opt
   ```
5. Create a desktop file

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and add the configuration below

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Eclipse JEE
   Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
   Icon=eclipse
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=Eclipse-JEE
   ```

   *12 Oct 2015 - Update with regards to eclipse.desktop:* The value for `icon` in eclipse.desktop should be path to `icon.xpm` instead of just `eclipse`. In my case, the absolute path was `/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm`.
6. Start eclipse via your launcher

<sub>Tested in 15.04 as VM and in a native 15.04 installation.</sub>

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ubuntu-make` to easily install Eclipse on Ubuntu.

> Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the
>   latest version of popular developer tools on your installation,
>   installing it longside all the required dependencies (which will only
>   ask for root access if you don't have all the required dependencies
>   installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if you are on a
>   64 bit machine, integrate it with the Unity launcher… Basically, **one
>   command to get your system ready to develop with!** - [Ubuntu
>   Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make)

---

**Installing Ubuntu Make :**

Ubuntu make is already in official Ubuntu 15.04 repositories, run :

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

**Installing Eclipse :**

```
umake ide eclipse
```

Comment: Tried your option but eclipse does not appear to be an option using umake, only 'lighttable' and 'visual-studio-code' seem to be options.

Comment: Worked just fine for me.