# Eclipse Marketplace

Tags: 14.04, java, eclipse, programming, ide

I have installed Eclipse with:

```
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

Now I doesn't find the Eclipse Marketplace in the menu "Help".

Where is the Marketplace or how can I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse in the Ubuntu repositories is too old. Therefore remove the installation via

```
sudo apt-get remove eclipse
```

and install Eclipse Mars as described in my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/674017/367165).