# Install eclipse + eclim in a headless server

Tags: server, java, eclipse, headless

I am trying to install eclipse + [elim](http://eclim.org/install.html) in a remote linux server where there is no internet connection and no display available (I am accessing the server using putty). Also I don't have root access in this server. eclim is installed successfully in the server but when I am trying to run eclimd it is throwing error like below:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/ui/PlatformUI
        at org.eclim.eclipse.EclimApplication.shutdown(EclimApplication.java:144)
        at org.eclim.eclipse.EclimApplication$1.run(EclimApplication.java:102)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI cannot be found by org.eclim_2.5.0
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:439)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:344)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:160)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 2 more
```

How can I run eclimd in this server?

Comment: Your question is, "How to install eclipse in a headless environment?". Right?

Comment: Not only eclipse also eclim...

Comment: You said, eclim is installed.

Comment: Yes installed but not running properly.

Comment: To install eclipse, try step 1 to 4 from my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/674017/367165

Comment: I don't have root permission to run apt-get

Comment: Is Java installed? `java -version`

Comment: Yes java installed and working properly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31177/discussion-between-a-b-and-chanchal1987).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say you do not have root access, the following steps install everything to your home folder:

### Download and install eclipse

1. Download eclipse [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/), eg. [Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 64-bit](https://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/1/eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz).
2. Extract the archive, change the name of the archive if necessary

   ```
    tar xf eclipse-jee-mars-1-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz -C ~
   ```

### Install and run eclim

1. Install `eclim` with `-Declipse.home="$HOME/eclipse"`

   Check the filename `eclim_2.5.0.jar` and replace it if necessary

   ```
    java -Dvim.files=$HOME/.vim -Declipse.home="$HOME/eclipse" -jar eclim_2.5.0.jar install
   ```
2. Run `eclimd`

   ```
    ./eclipse/eclimd -b
   ```

<sub>Partially taken from [here](http://eclim.org/install.html#install-headless)</sub>

Comment: can eclim and eclimd and eclipse not be installed with umake?