# How to install Eclipse using its installer

Tags: eclipse

I downloaded the Linux Eclipse installer from its site. By default, it is installed in home folder. No desktop shortcuts nothing else. Just a copy to a folder.

How can I install it the same way as is installed by `sudo apt-get install eclipse`?

Comment: Yes Eclipse is in the repos, you don't need that version from the site, you can install by terminal.

Comment: @markkirby have you ever checked the version in the Ubuntu repository?

Comment: Nope, I don't use it but OP never asked about versions, just can they install via `sudo apt-get install eclipse` or do you think I miss read this question ? @A.B.

Comment: The version in the repositories is old and the official installer is an easy way to install a recent version.

Comment: Would you please post the full name of the file with its extension?

Comment: eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz

Answer (score 45):

Here are all instructions. You have to create a desktop file, see the last point in my answer.

1. **Download the installer [here](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)**
2. **Extract the archive, e.g the 64-bit version**

   ```
   tar xf eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz
   ```
3. **Change your folder**

   ```
   cd eclipse-installer
   ```
4. **Run the installer *WITHOUT* `sudo` to *UPGRADE* the installer**

   ```
   ./eclipse-inst
   ```

   - Note the yellow exclamation mark in the top right corner.

     [image]
   - Activate the hamburger menu to upgrade the installer.

     [image]
   - **Close** the installer after the upgrade
5. **Install Eclipse without *OR* with `sudo` rights**

   - *Without `sudo` to install Eclipse in your home folder*

     ```
     ./eclipse-inst
     ```

     - select your Eclipse distribution

       [image]
     - and use a path inside your home folder

       [image]
   - ***OR with** `sudo` to install Eclipse in `/opt`.*

     ```
     sudo ./eclipse-inst
     ```

     - select your Eclipse distribution

       [image]
     - and use `/opt` as installation path

       [image]
6. **Finished**

   [image]
7. **Create a desktop file**

   Crazy, we have a installer but no desktop files. Perhaps, this will be fixed in future versions of the installer. In the meantime:

   ```
   nano ~/.local/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   and add the configuration below. Note, you have to change the pach for `Exec` and/or `Icon` if you have used a different location.

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Encoding=UTF-8
   Version=1.0
   Type=Application
   Name=Eclipse IDE
   Comment=Eclipse Integrated Development Environment
   Icon=/opt/eclipse/java-mars/eclips/icon.xpm
   Exec=/opt/eclipse/java-mars/eclips/eclipse
   StartupNotify=true
   StartupWMClass=java-mars
   ```

Comment: But still the system does not know that it is installed. `sudo apt-get install eclipse` tried to install it again.

Comment: Don't do that. The version in the repositories is old

Comment: Also the if I sudo install it. it is not run normally. It can be run only with sudo.

Comment: Yes, for `apt-get` you need always `sudo`

Comment: Use the installer as described in my answer ynd you will be happy.

Comment: It says: `The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library`. When I run eclipse in opt.

Comment: That's a different problem. Please ask a new question and give me more details. And you should accept this answer with a click on the check mark at the left side of the answer.

Comment: @A.B. - I don't think that is a separate question.  This method doesn't work using sudo.  I am also getting the same thing.

Comment: Agree with the sudo part, the answer is correct but I would remove the sudo part it may cause confusion and conflicts @A.B.

Comment: When I don't use sudo, I can't install it in /opt ! it says folder cannot be created, which of course means no permission to create !?

Comment: Procedure works for me in Ubuntu 16. Note: to get the latest version of eclipse (dubbed: NEON), select the "IDE for Java Developers" in the installer, even if you want to use it for python (pydev). The "Standard Eclipse" option installs a older version of eclipse.

Comment: i created a short cut icon for the eclipse executable file instead of the last step, felt it was less work

Comment: How to **un**install Eclipse installed via installer?

Answer (score 13):

Unfortunately I don't have enough points to write a reply to the above [answer by A.B](https://askubuntu.com/a/695401/662499). There is only one more step that you need to take if you want to install the application for all users under `/opt`:

You need to switch to the advanced mode and change the bundle pool folder to something like `/opt/eclipse/.p2/pool`. This is because when installing it with sudo, the installer chooses `/root/.p2/pool` by default for the bundle pool location, which can't be opened by your user. After that you should be able to open eclipse from your regular user. Hope this helps.

Comment: ... this change has to be done in eclipse.ini of Eclipse root

Answer (score 5):

Eclipse is now available as a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/eclipse). You can install it easily with one simple command:-

```
snap install eclipse --classic
```

This single snap will work on Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 17.10 and 18.04.

You will need to ensure Java is installed:

- [How do I install Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48468/how-do-i-install-java)

Comment: Whoever you are, where ever you are from. God Bless you, man! Worked Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The jre part is missing and is simple as

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Then run the `sudo ./eclipse-inst`

The online installer hung up on me I was using ubuntu GNOME 16.4, So I had to installed the specific version of eclipse from

```
www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/
```

Answer (score 1):

If you face issue while installing Eclipse, just check your connected network allowing you to access websites for installation. While installing eclipse communicate to server for the verification of Certificate.