# Eclipse installation : unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library

Tags: software-installation, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I install Eclipse Mars on Ubuntu 15.10 following this post:
[How to install Eclipse using its installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer/695401)

and lunch it after installation.

I install in `/opt folder` with `sudo ./eclipse-inst`

Than I create start Icon, following post, and after that when I try to start Eclipse I got this message:
eclipse-executable-launcher-error-unable-to-locate-companion-shared-library
and it is not possible to start it.

Any idea what happened?

this is message which I got when try to start from terminal:

```
../../../../root/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.300.v20150602-1417: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

Hi,

actually when I try to start Eclipse from Terminal with sudo and type my password I can start it. It seems Eclipse doesn't have enough privileges to start.

Does anybody has idea what to do?
To change a privileges for the whole folder where Eclipse is installed?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure it is the best solution, but it worked for me:

- remove old installation
- open installer as sudo
- open the menu in the upper-right corner of the installer and turn OFF Bundle Pools
- install the version you need
- after the installation is completed go to /opt and change the owner of the eclipse folder. It should be something like sudo chown -R user:group eclipse_folder

The part I'm not sure about is the removal of the first installation. I just deleted the folder, but I'm afraid there's more stuff left behind in different folders.

Comment: @guest comments: to turn OFF Bundle Pools worked for me too but, I totally agree with the previous comment, this shouldn't be enabled by default. Computers are hard for most people already and a programmer may not have deep knowledge on changing the system configuration either or may not find this article. Hopefully, this will be solved on next release.

Comment: Turning OFF Bundle Pools Totally fixed my issue! Thank you very much friend!

Answer (score 3):

With version 'neon' of eclipse, you only have to turn off "bundle pools" and the installer will create a non-root executable version of eclipse.

Comment: It is insane that the default option (or any option) creates an install that cannot be used by non-root users.