# How to install Eclipse Neon using its installer for all users?

Tags: software-installation, eclipse

I have followed the instructions [from this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/695401/344199) to similar question, but it looks like the installer in sudo mode installs most of plugins to /root/.p2/pool/plugins, so you can't access it in non-sudo mode.

I have copied .p2 folder (`/root/.p2`) to my install folder (`/opt/eclipse/`) and changed launcher library path in eclipse.ini file to point to the new location.

Unfortunately, that did not help:

```
An error has occurred.  See the log file
/home/michal-praca/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.0_1942444138_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/1469604630174.log

!SESSION Wed Jul 27 09:25:23 CEST 2016 -----------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-07-27 09:25:23.561
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_1.0.200.v20160504-1419.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-07-27 09:25:23.565
!MESSAGE Could not find extension: reference:file:org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.nashorn.extension_1.0.0.v201605131737.jar
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2016-07-27 09:25:23.570
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:670)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
```

How to install Eclipse Neon using installer in such a way, that any user on the system can use it?

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: I tried it with `sudo ./eclipse-inst` and manually requested  the /opt/eclipse directory tree, and although it said it completed, all I found in /opt/eclipse was a tree structure with install logs. It ran a long time for each product (I was trying to install Java, Android, and C++), as if it was getting a lot done, but it didn't actually install.

Comment: OK, I've made progress, I think, based on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864572/using-different-location-for-eclipses-p2-file , which tells me to deselect the "bundle pools" button when installing into /opt/eclipse . My guess is that the installer builds things into /opt/eclipse in a way that doesn't work if you just copy /root/.p2 over.

Comment: @Steve you've got the answer there, and its still relevant today, maybe you want to post it as an answer?