# Add symbolic link or add to path?

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link, paths

I installed the latest version of Eclipse using the installer wizard.
(I was following the instructions in the following [link](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/01/how-to-install-the-latest-eclipse-in-ubuntu-16-04-15-10/).)

I can run eclipse from the command line as follows:

```
$ ~/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse
```

I was wondering if I could set it up so that I can run Eclipse by just typing:

```
$ eclipse
```

However, I am not sure whether it is "better"
to add the folder `~/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/` to the PATH,
or to add a symbolic link to the `eclipse` executable
to one of the directories in the current PATH.
(In case it is recommended to add a symbolic link,
which of the directories is preferred?)

Comment: "Better" varies

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an alias in .bashrc file in the home folder
`alias eclipse=~/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/695401/548384, you can follow 7 in order to create a desktop icon