# How do I install a .tar.gz file?

Tags: files, eclipse, tar

I have the file **eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz** of the URL :

[origin of file](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/neon/R3/eclipse-inst-linux64.tar.gz)

I want  install it  in my ubuntu But I don't know how to install it. How do I install in ubuntu?

Comment: first use ark to decompress it.

Comment: tar.gz is a tarball. 

it's like a 'zip' file; but in an older *nix way.

the gz tells you its gzip'd & tar tells you its multiple files tarballed into a single file suitable for writing to tape etc.  the unix way was do one thing & do it well; so one command compressed (bzip, gzip being different types of compression) & another combined (tarball)

expand & then you'll see the readme & other files, and can install.  it can be done from command prompt, or a tool such as @ravery said. I'll not go further as covered elsewhere as Sumeet Deshmukh said

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer