# Difficulties to maintain and to move the Eclipse launcher icon in the desktop toolbar

Tags: launcher, icons, eclipse

I have installed in the Eclipse IDE version 4.9.0 through the installer provided on the "Eclipse" home site and everything has worked well.
After that, I have launched this application with the command line:
---->/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse/eclipse

Then the application started normally and the Eclipse Icon appeared correctly in the toolbar.
After that I tried to access the Icon configuration but I couldn't manage to find out the right item in the menus in order to make this Icon permanent.
And the consequence of this is that the Eclipse Icon disappears when I close the application.
Usually, when I install applications through the Ubuntu package manager, I don't get any problems to make the application Icon permanent.
But through a manual package installation, the Icon behaviour seems to be different.
Many thanks if somebody has an idea to help me.
Cordially
Bye
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by AndAC's answer to [How can I add "Show desktop" to the GNOME dash or Ubuntu Dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/903532/how-can-i-add-show-desktop-to-the-gnome-dash-or-ubuntu-dock), here is a method to add a launcher for Eclipse to the Gnome dash:

Create a file `eclipse.desktop` in the directory `$HOME/.local/share/applications` containing the text

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse/icon.xpm
Exec=/opt/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse/eclipse
```

Open Gnome's application menu, search for "eclipse", and draw the icon which appears to the dash.

Answer (score 0):

After I thought the "Eclipse 4.9.0" installation  procedure I followed, I remembered that I forgot to create manually the desktop file as explained in page with the link 
below:
[[How to install Eclipse using its installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/695382/how-to-install-eclipse-using-its-installer][1])

If you read this page, you will see that it's a bug of eclipse installer since the installer normally should do this job.
Then I got the idea that maybe there was a link between the Eclipse Icon behaviour problem and the lack of this file.
And I was right since after I created this eclipse desktop file then now magically the "Eclipse Icon" behaves normally and it keeps its  place when I move it inside the desktop bar.
Sorry for the disturb, it was my fault.
Cordially
Bye
Mark